# Unresolved reference: ExpandLess

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Iam complete new to Kotlin and to Jetpack Compose
i have made the Jetpack Compose basics (CodeAlong) and at the end it keeps saying Unresolved reference Expandless ore Unresolved reference: ExpandMore.
Can someone help me find the Right thing?!

I searched a bit but my Knowledge isn't big enough to find an answer[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/01Q1n.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be an import for `Icons.Filled` missing. Please try to change your code to:

```
imageVector = if (expanded) Icons.Filled.ExpandLess else Icons.Filled.ExpandMore
```

If that does not resolve your issue, check the dependencies in your module's `build.gradle` file and try to add the following line:

```
implementation "androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended:1.5.4"
```

If Android Studio asks to to synchronize the Gradle files, click okay.

Comment: oh yes that worked
I just had to add the file to build grade
Thanks

Comment: I am happy to hear that! You can mark this answer as accepted by clicking the green checkmark to the left of the answer. Thank you :)